# R:Error in names(x) <- value: 'names' attribute must be the same length as the vector

Tags: r

When I run my code (below), I get this error:

"Error in names(x) <- value :
'names' attribute must be the same length as the vector"

## Code:

```
stas <- c('01613900','01615000','01616100','01620500','01621050', '01626850','01663500')
for (sta in stas){
  q <- readNWISdv(sta, parameterCd = "00060", startDate = beg.Date, endDate = end.Date)
  
  q <- q[,-c(1,2,5)]
  
  colnames(q) <- c("date",sta)  
  if (which(sta==stas) == 1){
    qf <- q
  }else{
    qf <- full_join(qf, q) 
  }
}
```

Some "sta" (siteID) do not have values and need to skip those "sta" in for loop.
I am stuck on an error in R and don't know how to fix it. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

Chintamani

Comment: Just a guess:  you need backticks (top left of most keyboards) around dataframe column names that start with numbers.  Try working with names like `v01613900` instead of  `01613900`.

Comment: What does `q` look like? Can you provide a sample of the result from `readNWISdv`? Seems like the problem is that `q` doesn't have exactly 2 columns when you assign `colnames(q)`, but without data we can't run your example and test for ourselves.